# batch conversion of tiff stack to individual tiff images

Tags: images, image-manipulation

Are there any CLIs that accept a tiff stack as input and write individual tiff images as output, preferably to stdout for piping directly to an image viewer?

Answer (score 3):

Imagemagick's `convert` command can change a multipage TIFF into multiple files

`convert multipage.tif single%d.tif`

The `%d` will get replaced by a page number making the single images.

You could also convert to other image formats at the same time, for instance

`convert multipage.tif single%d.png`

For your other part of the question, I'm not sure how a viewer would know how to separate one image from another as they come through a pipe.

In a similar question on SuperUser, there was a discussion of some formating problems some kinds of multi page tiff files seem to have.  Just in case, you may want to look at https://superuser.com/questions/1051357/how-do-i-separate-a-tiff-stack-into-several-pngs-or-a-single-pdf/1051796#1051796

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful command for quickly deconstructing the entire stack (I was previously doing this using a loop). As far as piping into image viewing software, since the output data presumably has image headers punctuating the stream of image data, I would think these could be exploited to determine the beginning/end of images in the sequence.